# Representing Multiple Payment Methods

Tags: sql, oracle, database-design

I have a situation where customers are able to pay via either a credit card or by a PayPal account. I currently have a super class as 'customer' with two sub-types of 'public' and 'commercial'. However, both types can pay by either form of payment, as well as have multiple credit cards / PayPal accounts associated with them.

I have a current model that works, but not for having multiple cards etc. I eventually need to be able to query what customer paid by what method. For example, how many customers during a time period paid via credit card.

The model minus the payment details look's similar to:

[ORDER]-----[CUSTOMER]---(D)---[PUBLIC][COMMERCIAL]

Answer (score 1):

It should not be a problem to pull that kind of query in SQL. If you added the tables for payment accounts and PAYPAL_ACCOUNT and CREDITCARD_ACCOUNT need to be two separate tables you would associate those to CUSTOMER and to ORDER but not to PUBLIC or COMMERCIAL.

You could use LEFT JOIN in SQL to have rows show up that don't include every table. This will fill the fields in a table with null for example when it is an order from a PUBLIC account and you look at the COMMERCIAL table

```
SELECT * from ORDER o
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER c on c.ID = o.CustomerID
LEFT JOIN PUBLIC p on p.CustomerID = c.ID
LEFT JOIN COMMERCIAL co on co.CustomerID = c.ID
LEFT JOIN PAYPAL_ACCOUNT pa on pa.ID = o.PaypalAccountID
LEFT JOIN CREDITCARD_ACCOUNT cc on cc.ID = o.CreditCardAccountID
```

and then you can add where clause at the end to narrow it down

```
WHERE o.PaypalAccountID is not null
```

to pull up only Paypal

Comment: When you say associate those two tables (Because I do already have them), how are you suggesting to do that? Include a linking table between CUSTOMER and ORDER... Say, PAYMENT that links to CREDITCARD and PAYPAL? @TomEsch

Comment: If it works well on the platform you are on I would add two fields to ORDER , one that is PaypalID and one that is a CreditCardID, and just fill in the appropriate one and leave the other one null. Make those fields foreign keys to the PAYPAL_ACCOUNT and CREDITCARD_ACCOUNT ID fields.

Comment: I have already considered that concept however, I do not like the idea of accepting nulls and have avoided it in all other tables across the DB. The payment methods have to have a relationship with CUSTOMER and ORDER. I am fine with repeating cust_id in a table when they have multiple cards / paypal accounts. @TomEsch

Comment: If you prefer not to use nulls, you can set up that ORDER to default to -1 as the value for the ID of the two different accounts it could have.